# How do I convert a video to GIF with text overlay using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm currently trying to modify this command, which uses the [split](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#split_002c-asplit) command from ffmpeg to make a gif

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 30 -t 3 -i input.flv -filter_complex "fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos[x];[x]split[x1][x2];[x1]palettegen[p];[x2][p]paletteuse" output.gif
```

This works fine, the problem is when I try and add in a text overlay to the gif using the `golden ratio`

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 30 -t 3 -i "input.mp4" -filter_complex "fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos[x],drawtext=box=1:boxcolor=black@0.4:boxborderw=5:fontfile=font3.ttf:text='Stackoverflow':fontsize=24:fontcolor=white:x=(w-tw)/2:y=(h/PHI)+th[x];[x]split[x1][x2];[x1]palettegen[p];[x2][p]paletteuse" output.gif
```

Now I'm not sure if I need to add in another variable to the paletteuse? I'm trying to run this in one pass

The error says

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2016-01-21 04:12:34
  Duration: 00:04:24.38, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 730 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 632 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 95 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-01-21 04:12:35
      handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 0 on filter Parsed_drawtext_2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the drawtext in sequence of the first few filters.

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 30 -t 3 -i "input.mp4"
  -filter_complex "fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos,
   drawtext=box=1:boxcolor=black@0.4:boxborderw=5:fontfile=font3.ttf:text='Stackoverflow':fontsize=24:fontcolor=white:x=(w-tw)/2:y=(h/PHI)+th,
   split[x1][x2];[x1]palettegen[p];[x2][p]paletteuse" output.gif
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, this nice tool provides the same functionalities plus some extra and also has a user friendly GUI:

https://github.com/lettier/gifcurry

Install is straightforward on Ubuntu:

```
wget https://github.com/lettier/gifcurry/releases/download/6.0.0.0/gifcurry-6.0.0.0-x86_64.AppImag

chmod u+x gifcurry-6.0.0.0-x86_64.AppImage

./gifcurry-6.0.0.0-x86_64.AppImage
```

Enjoy.